# To break up Ruby class into separate files by mixins or plain definitions?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.2

What is the preferred way of breaking up a class into multiple files? Mixins could work, but in my case I just want to better organize a very large class. Of the two methods featured below, is one of them "better" than the other?

file_A.rb

```
require 'file_B_class'
require 'file_B_mixin'

class ReallyBigClass
  include ReallyBigClassFileB

   def primary_method
    puts "I'm the primary method"
  end
end
```

file_B_class.rb

```
class ReallyBigClass

  def support_method_as_class
    puts "I'm included in the main class by appending code"
  end

end
```

file_B_mixin.rb

```
 module ReallyBigClassFileB

  def support_method_as_mixin
    puts "I'm included in the main class by mixin"
  end
end
```

Comment: Breaking a class like this will not solve anything. It will just make the problem worse by masking it somewhat.

Comment: As @max says, your class is doing too much. Extract some of its responsibilities into focused, smaller, manageable classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your support methods general enough that they might be useful for other totally unrelated classes? If so, a mixin is the proper way to do this, since it lets you easily reuse the support code.

However if your support methods are very specific to ReallyBigClass and are unlikely to work if included somewhere else, reopening the class is the way to go. Using a mixin there could give the appearance that the methods are more general than they really are, when really they should only be used with instances of a specific class.

That being said, I think your question indicates a larger design problem. If you are in the former case (general methods), you should be designing more general modules in the first place to avoid tight coupling. A module called `ReallyBigClassFileB` gives off some strong code smell. In the latter case (very specific methods) if your class is so big that its file is unmanageably large you probably need to refactor something. Maybe your class is responsible for too much? Maybe it could use some subclasses (which make sense in separate files)?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The support methods are specific to the class and should not be reused, so I will go with reopening the class. In this particular case the class is not unmanageably large yet but I am considering organizing its methods by category for aesthetic reasons.